# NativeScript installation Errors - npm fibers

Tags: android, node.js, nativescript, node-fibers

Notes:

```
Node version 7.0.0
JavaJDK version 1.8.0.112 
Android API 22 and studio installed:
```

I have been following the installation instructions on the native script website and am failing to get it to install at all.
I have setup all my environment variables correctly for JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME
But whenever I try to install the nativescript cli i get errors like this:[image]

I tried looking up the internet for some solutions and found some initial clues on trying to edit the fibers module source code as given [here](https://github.com/meteor/node-fibers/commit/d519f0c5971c33d99c902dad346b817e84bab001) : 
I have tried building the fibers module by force

```
npm build -f
```

in the npm fibers directory. Since the nativescript installation fails I also cant run the tns doctor for any log trace:
[image]
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to help me fix this. Do let me know if you need any more information. Apologies if my english isn't great as it is not my first language .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Node version which is not supported yet, bellow is list of possible version as stated at http://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win or other two version for Linux/Mac. Downgrade to 6.x version or you can use `nvm`, manager which can be used with several Node versions at same PC

> The latest Node.js 0.10.x, 0.12.x, 4.x, 5.x, or 6.x stable official release

Comment: I had same problem :D when 6.x wasn't supported yet :)

Comment: NativeScript team is working to resolve this issue - you can track it at the following link: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/pull/2157